# How does CSS height get applied to input fields?

Tags: html, css

I'm having some difficulty understanding how the css height property is applied to `input` fields when i use `em` as a unit.

Take a look at this jsfiddle: [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ufqx8jpa/)

If the `em` value is equal to the base font size examples one and three should be the same height.  If `em` is based on what the font size is set to in the element (which I believe is correct), then examples one and two should be the same size.  As it is, none of these items are the same size.  If I set the height to `px` then I can force them to all be the same size.

What is coming into play that makes all of my input boxes a different size?

CSS:

```
.one {
  max-height:3em;
  height: 3em;
  font-size:1em;
  vertical-align: top;
}

.two {
  max-height:6em;
  height: 6em;
  font-size: 0.5em;
  vertical-align:top;
}

.three {
  max-height:3em;
  height: 3em;
  font-size: 0.5em;
  vertical-align:top;
}
```

HTML:

```
<input type="text" class="one" placeholder="one">
<input type="text" class="two" placeholder="two">
<input type="text" class="three" placeholder="three">
```

Comment: What are you on about? Example 1 and 2 ARE the same size. And it's working just as intended. The base font-size you've set, times the height set == actual height. Hence the first input is 3em high, the second input is 3em high, and the last input is 1.5em high.

Comment: They do not display the same for me in Chrome 54 or Safari 10.  What browser are you using where they are the same size?  In both of the browsers I'm using they are clearly not the same.  Example 2 is about 10% taller than example 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This actually seems like a bug in Chrome / Safari. Firefox and Opera renders them correctly.

One way to fix this so it renders the same in all browsers, are to use `rem` instead of `em`: https://www.sitepoint.com/understanding-and-using-rem-units-in-css/

However, this has other potential pitfalls and implications

Comment: Well that would make this all make sense.  I had actually moved over to using rem in this case already, but I still wanted to understand the core of what was happening.  If it is a bug, then I can at least forget about it and just move on.

Answer (score 1):

> If `em` is based on what the font size is set to in the element (which
>   I believe is correct)

No, that is incorrect.

The `em` given for the height is based on the elements parent's font-size, not the font size given to the element itself.

The font size of the input, when `em` is used, is also based/inherited from its parents font size.

So this is kind of the whole idea, so they scale equal if parent's font size changes.

Here is a sample showing that

```css
div {
  font-size: 30px;
  margin: 20px 0;
}
.em1 {
  font-size: 1em;
}
.em2 {
  font-size: 2em;
}
.one {
  max-height:3em;
  height: 3em;
  font-size:1em;
  vertical-align: top;
}

.two {
  max-height:6em;
  height: 6em;
  font-size: 0.5em;
  vertical-align:top;
}

.three {
  max-height:3em;
  height: 3em;
  font-size: 0.5em;
  vertical-align:top;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <input type="text" class="one" placeholder="one">
  <input type="text" class="two" placeholder="two">
  <input type="text" class="three" placeholder="three">
</div>

<div class="em1">
  <input type="text" class="one" placeholder="one">
  <input type="text" class="two" placeholder="two">
  <input type="text" class="three" placeholder="three">
</div>

<div class="em2">
  <input type="text" class="one" placeholder="one">
  <input type="text" class="two" placeholder="two">
  <input type="text" class="three" placeholder="three">
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, this does help.  

One question though - in your example, if you replace the `div` `font-size` with `2em` then 1 and 2 are the same height.  If it is `1em` none are the same height.  They seem to converge in height at around `1.2em`.  I'm having difficulty understanding this behaviour even if the base font size for `div` is inherited.

Comment: @WillyC Updated my answer with 2 more sample, having `1em` and `2em`,  all 3 behave how they should, equal height on input 1 and 2, so if your doesn't, you probably missed something

Comment: The second div in your example has no input boxes with equal height on  Chrome 54 or Safari 10 (which is the same result I get in jsfiddle with my example).  Also, even without the surrounding div, shouldn't they all be inheriting a common font size from a single parent, and thus not have differing input box sizes?  I get how the model works when you are specifying a specific font size in a parent div, but why is that div even required?  Shouldn't input boxes 1 and 2 have a common parent with a common font size anyway?

Comment: @WillyC I just tested this on Firefox, Edge, IE11 and all work fine, so it has to be a bug in on Chrome 54 or Safari 10

Comment: thanks.  It is much easier for me to understand this if it is just a bug in webkit based browsers.  I learned from your answer even if this did end up just being a bug.

Answer (score 0):

This is because you are using `em` that is equal to the computed font-size for the element to which the em is applied. For a better explaination read [this](https://www.sitepoint.com/power-em-units-css/).